# How to populate longitude latitude from JSON file into array

Tags: ios, json

I need to find the nearest cities around my current location. Would you advice me how should I populate the coordinates into an array in my project and how to calculate the distance between my location and the nearest around me. I have to display the distance in (KM) and the city name ,so that the user can choose which city best fits for him.I also need to call the coordinates and the names in my code from a json file
My JSON File is:

```
 {
"City A": {
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 9.96233,
        "Latitude": 49.80404
    }
},
"City B": {
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 6.11499,
        "Latitude": 50.76891
    }
},
"City C": {
    "Position": {
        "Longitude": 6.80592,
        "Latitude": 51.53548
    }
```

and my function so far:

```
  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userlocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userlocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userlocation.coordinate.longitude)

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.5)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

    Mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    let locations = ["42.6977,23.3219","43.6977,24.3219"]

    let distanceMeters = userlocation.distanceFromLocation(CLLocation(latitude: 42.6977,longitude: 23.3219))
    let distanceKilometers = distanceMeters / 1000.00
    let roundedDistanceKilometers = String(Double(round(100 * distanceKilometers) / 100)) + " km"
   // var distanceMeter = NSString(format: "\(distanceKilometers)km")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JSON file is in the application bundle and is named `cities.json` first create a custom struct `City`

```
struct City {
  let name : String
  let location : CLLocation
}
```

Then in your controller declare an array `cities`

```
 var cities = [City]()
```

To populate the array deserialize the JSON and extract the data

```
guard let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("cities", withExtension: "json"), jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else { return }

do {
  let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
  for (cityName, position) in jsonObject {
    let coordinates = position["Position"] as! [String:CLLocationDegrees]
    let longitude = coordinates["Longitude"]!
    let latitude = coordinates["Latitude"]!
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude,longitude: longitude)
    let city = City(name: cityName, location: location)
     cities.append(city)
    // print(cities)
  }
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

To find the nearest location you could sort the array by distance

```
let nearestCity = cities.sort({ userLocation.distanceFromLocation($0.location) < userLocation.distanceFromLocation($1.location) }).first
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, but how do you compare the user current location with the other locations?

Comment: Would you check Why I get an error here:
        let nearestCity = cities.sort({ userLocation.distanceFromLocation($0.location) < userLocation.distanceFromLocation($1.location) }).first

Comment: First of all please don't edit my answer. Add your new code to your question. Second of all: what error message do you get?

Comment: I am sorry the error is in this line:
let nearestCity = cities.sort({ userLocation.distanceFromLocation($0.location) < userLocation.distanceFromLocation($1.location) }).first

And it says that userLocation is not identified

Comment: Of course you have to implement that code in the environment where you receive the current location

Comment: Please check here, I have uploaded my code:
http://biobeehive.com/code-4/

The idea is when the user changes the UISlider, depending what range he choose, he gets only the cities which are in the range